# How to start and stop CMMotionManager startAccelerating and stopAccelerating while iphone in accelerate mode or in idle mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I am developing app related to accelerating. I'm using `CMMtionManager` object. but when I call `startaccelerating` method its working and continuously calling that method even iphone in idle mode. **How to stop and start accelerating while iphone accelerating and idle.**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    motionManager=[[CMMotionManager alloc]init];
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval=2;



- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

     [self startMyMotionDetect];     
}



- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];   
 // Request to stop receiving accelerometer events and turn off accelerometer

}


- (CMMotionManager *)motionManager
{
   motionManager = nil;

    id appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    if ([appDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(motionManager)]) {
        motionManager = [appDelegate motionManager];
    }

    return motionManager;
}
- (void)startMyMotionDetect
{    NSLog(@"active %d",motionManager.accelerometerActive);

     NSLog(@"availabilty %d",motionManager.accelerometerAvailable);



    [motionManager 
     startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error)
     {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                        NSLog(@"hello");
                            [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
                        });   

     }];
}
```

please assist me.

Comment: What do you mean by idle mode? If you accelerate your phone with 3g constantly for 1 sec it moves with 30 m/s but its acceleration might be 0 then. Is this idle? Or do you mean the app is in background? Where are these `startaccelerating` and `stopaccelerating` methods mentioned in the title?

Comment: @Kay Thanks for comment.when i start accelerating im getting accelerate data with x,y,z values.when i stop the accelerate the device. im still getting the x,y,z values. its varying even iphone in idel means no accelerating.

Comment: I see. If you use raw accelerometer values, you always have gravity included. The [magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_%28mathematics%29) is about 9.81. Life is easier when using [DeviceMotion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html). See [Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW18) about how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to add this?:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(stopAccelerometer)
                                          name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification 
                                        object:nil];
```

Comment: no its not working.how to stop accelerometer when my iphone not accelerate

Comment: I think you can create a float x,y,z variable and check the value, if the difference are = 0 for each variable, you can stop. But how can you detect the Accelerometer if you stoped it? why do you want stop the check?

Comment: im getting accelerometer data x,y,z but those values like 0.123,0.335,0.234 like coming even i stop the accelerating iphone device.

Comment: if your Xprev=0.123 Yprev=0.335 and Zprev=0.234 and x,y,z actual are the same, or a little bit different you can stop. For riactivate, you can start a timer that check te new difference between your time interval